# How to prevent the debug toolbar from appearing in a prod environment

Tags: symfony1

I have recently deployed a Symfony 1.3.6 website. I have chosen to keep frontend_dev.php on the server, so I can debug on the local machine when absolutely required.

I modified frontend_dev.php like this:

```
<?php

require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/../config/ProjectConfiguration.class.php');

$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);

// this check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// feel free to remove this, extend it or make something more sophisticated.
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')))
{
    //in case something screwy happens ...
    try
    {
       // die('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
       sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->getController()->forward('security', 'error404');
       exit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        //if we got here, all bets are off anyway, just go away ....
        exit();
    }
}

sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

What I was doing was to direct the request to a 404 error page. However, I notice that when I typed in http://www.mywebsite.com/frontend_dev.php/some_valid_url.html

I was directed to the 404 page (as I wanted) - BUT the debug toolbar was shown - ehich is obviously a security risk. What is the best way to disable the toolbar when the dev controller is accessed from a non-local machine?

I thought of putting checking code in the error404 action, and then disabling the debug toolbar as and when needed, but I am not sure if this is the most symfonic way to do it.

Whats the best practice in this instance?

Comment: Personally I've just added my IP address to the array in your code to allow temporary access to the frontend_dev controller, and then just removed it.

Answer (score 9):

`sfConfig::set('sf_web_debug', false);`

Comment: This will just turn off the debug toolbar. Still you will run your app in a dev environment which might have a different configuration.

Comment: Coronatus: This turns of the debug toolbar for the first (error404) page - but links on that page (back to the home page for example), still have the debug toolbar displayed

Comment: So put that line in a global file.

Comment: This helped me turn off the toolbar in an Ajax response.

Answer (score 6):

Wouldn't you just want to turn it off in the `settings.yml` file?

```
dev:
  .settings:
    web_debug: false
```

Answer (score 2):

You're initializing the configuration in a dev environment with debug turned on. Try something like:

```
// this check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// feel free to remove this, extend it or make something more sophisticated.
if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '::1')))
{
    //in case something screwy happens ...
    try
    {
       // die('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
       $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'prod', false);

       sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->getController()->forward('security', 'error404');
       exit();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        //if we got here, all bets are off anyway, just go away ....
        exit();
    }
}
else
{
  $configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
  sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
}
```